# Azure blob in ASP.NET MVC : signature fields not well formed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

Using the following code to generate SAS and attaching to blob url, it looks simple put unable to make it work

```
Dim sasUrl As String = imageUrl 'https://**blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/site/GroupImages/Tabs/image.png
Dim blobSasBuilder As Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder = New Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder() With {
                                                                                        .BlobContainerName = _azContainerName,
                                                                                        .StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-30),
                                                                                        .ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                                                                                    }
blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Read)
Dim sasToken = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(New StorageSharedKeyCredential(_azAccountName, _azAccountKey)).ToString()
sasUrl += "?" + sasToken

Return sasUrl
```

I get the following error:

> AuthenticationFailed
>
> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>
> RequestId: 83ab7db1-501e-0043-6a84-f2ac67000000
> Time: 2023-09-29T03:27:02.8112176Z
>
> Signature fields not well formed.

**Edit1 ::**

Using exact same code and yet the same problem, only difference is my blob name is in canonical format, here is the change I have

```
Dim blobClient As BlobClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_azCompanyContainerName).GetBlobClient("site/GroupImages/Tabs/pizza.png")

Dim blobSasBuilder As BlobSasBuilder = New BlobSasBuilder() With {
    .BlobContainerName = _azCompanyContainerName,
    .BlobName = "site/GroupImages/Tabs/pizza.png",
    .Resource = "b",
    .ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    .Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
}
```

**Edit 2::**

Whenever there is a "+" in the token, it fails. Following is invalid one which throws above mentioned error,

**sig=+Z9OWuihzHYWmdXToy53OS7y+PN2qtBPwhzgIYSsLTQ=**

Answer (score 1):

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.RequestId: 83ab7db1-501e-0043-6a84-f2ac67000000   Time:2023-09-29T03:27:02.8112176Z Signature fields not well formed

The above error message indicates that the SAS token is not well-formed. This could be due to an issue with the way the SAS token is generated.

You can use the below code to generate a SAS token with a URL using  **`vb.net`**.

**Code.**

```
Dim accountname As String = "xxxxx"
Dim accesskey As String = "xxxxxx"
Dim containername As String = "xxx"
Dim blobname As String = "xxxxx"
Dim credential As StorageSharedKeyCredential = New StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountname, accesskey)
Dim blobServiceClient As BlobServiceClient = New BlobServiceClient(New Uri($"https://{accountname}.blob.core.windows.net"), credential)
Dim blobClient As BlobClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containername).GetBlobClient(blobname)

' Create a BlobSasBuilder object
Dim blobSasBuilder As BlobSasBuilder = New BlobSasBuilder() With {
    .BlobContainerName = containername,
    .BlobName = blobname,
    .Resource = "b",
    .ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    .Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
}
blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Read)
Dim sasToken = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(credential).ToString()
Dim uriBuilder As UriBuilder = New UriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
uriBuilder.Query = sasToken
Dim blobsasURL As String = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString()
Console.WriteLine("SAS URL: " & blobsasURL)
```

**Output:**

```
SAS URL: https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test1/bike.png?sv=2023-08-03&spr=https&se=2023-09-29T10%3A46%3A04Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=xxxxxx
```

Copied the **`BLOB SAS URL`** and pasted it into the browser and it successfully displayed the image.

**Browser:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Create a service SAS for a blob with .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create-dotnet)

Comment: Still the same error, Edited my post to explain the issue

Comment: Can you edit with new code in your question about how you create the SAS token with URL ?